# using beautifulsoup to verify presence of class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, boolean

i'm trying to use beautifulsoup to check if a class is present on a website. 
I want to be able to return False if it isn't, True if it is.
I am getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Here are two urls to show the difference and the snippet of code i have.

Has class "style3"
http://www.wvlabor.com/new_searches/contractor_RESULTS.cfm?wvnumber=WV057788&contractor_name=&dba=&city_name=&County=&Submit3=Search+Contractors

Doesn't have class "style3"
http://www.wvlabor.com/new_searches/contractor_RESULTS.cfm?wvnumber=WV057888&contractor_name=&dba=&city_name=&County=&Submit3=Search+Contractors

```
def license_exists(soup):
    if soup.find('td', class = 'style3')
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
def license_exists(soup):
    if soup.find('td', class_ = 'style3'):  #or if soup.find('td', {'class':'style3'})
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

**Note**: `class` is a reserved keyword in python.

Comment: i'm getting an syntax error( ^ points to parentheses)      if soup.find('td', class_ = 'style3')
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Is it the `:` I missed in the solution?

Comment: omg...it's always the smallest things that mess it up.  thanks for the quick response.  :)